# Aptana/ Eclipse freeze on startup; Java problem

Tags: aptana-studio

I can't start Aptana or Eclipse IDE. Currently I work on Ubuntu 12.04 LTE. Before I have update to the last stable 13.04, but I have problems with my development tools, like SVN etc. Also problems with flicker on screen after a break or active screensaver.

Now I'm back on 12.04, 64 bit system. But it is not possible to start Aptana or Eclipse. It freeze always on the start image, nothing doing also nothing inside the process control.

I have re-install Java, also switch to Oracle JDK. Currently is installed openjdk-7.
I have clean the system, no packages or other software the have a problem.

I switch between the different java version, 6 or 7 of openjdk and oracle 7 with `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`.

I have also tested the 32bit openjdk version, `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk:i386`, same result, freeze on startup splash screen.

Now I have only installed the last open jdk 7: `java -version` : 1.7.0_25

I have also no workspace currently for Aptana. The install is new, now settings from older versions. I have also tested with the 32bit version and now back to the right version, last download of Aptana 64bit.

I have also start Aptana with the debug flag and get the follow feedback inside the console.

```
frank@frank-desktop:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3$ ./AptanaStudio3 -debug
Start VM: /usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
-name Aptana Studio 3
--launcher.library /opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so
-startup /opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata ab0008
-debug
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar 
Install location:
    file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/
Configuration file:
    file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/frank/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1287824591/configuration/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/frank/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1287824591/configuration/config.ini loaded
Shared configuration location:
    file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar
Splash location:
    /home/frank/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1287824591/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/com.aptana.rcp_3.4.2.201308081805/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 4
Starting application: 894
```

I have also try to load eclipse, pure, without plugins from Aptana or other, with tte `-debug -console`helper. Here my return.

```
frank@frank-desktop:/var/www$ eclipse -debug -console
Start VM: /usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.dist/eclipse_1408.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata c8003
-debug
-console
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar 
Install location:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/frank/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/frank/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/config.ini loaded
Shared configuration location:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.dist.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.dist.jar
Splash location:
    /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.2.dist/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/var/www/.options not found

osgi> Time to load bundles: 3
Starting application: 634
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have re-install Java, also switch to Oracle JDK. Currently is installed openjdk-7 -> you are using Openjdk 7, or Oracle JDK 7 ?

Comment: I have test with OpenJDK 6 and 7 and als Oracle 7, same result :( Doy ou have install the java version from 64bit? I have only tested with 64bit installs of Java and Eclipse, Aptana.

Comment: installing java is not enough, you have to tell the system which version of java it should use !

Comment: I have tell the system, which version I will use. I test with 6 and 7 and Oracle 7. I switch between the version with `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`, right?

Comment: Don't forget to update-alternatives for java as well. Java is used to run ecipse, javac is used to compile java source into byte-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crazy, the problem on this lot of hours debugging was a problem with the developer before the client!

If I start the Eclipse or Aptane App, then start the application with a popupfor asking the folder for workspace. This popup window was on my second screen, there is not in the same room. Only with Super + S was possible to see this window. I have in a bit of applications the problem, that she open windows on the wrong screen - but this is a other topic.

Now, I'm happy and so much lucky. I can work for clients with my default IDE and have a lot of fun for the next weeks, when I think about my crazy stuff on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have the latest version of Eclipse installed visit the following webpage that explains how to install any Eclipse version on Ubuntu (the latest version from the web)

http://terminaltwister.com/installing-eclipse-kepler-4-3-in-ubuntu-13-04/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I have also tested in my debugging workflow with the last version of Eclipse, Kepler.